# Variables in Tasker

Tags: tasker, automation

how can I write Text directly after a variable in Tasker without making Tasker think that the variable name is the actual variable name plus the text after it?

20%DATE3-%DATE1-%DATE2T%TIME1:%TIME2:00+01:00

I basically want the "%DATE2" being read as the Variable name and the "T" read as text.

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes around the variable name?

Comment: @Firelord what do you mean? Those: ""? If so, they don't work.